# Erro ao executar comando Oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Galera, boa tarde,

Estou com problema pra chamar uma função no Oracle... A função é essa:

```
function mataSessao(){
    $connect = oci_connect('xxxx','xxxx','xxxxx','xxxxx');
    $IDSESSAO = $_POST['idsessao'];
    $IDSERIAL = $_POST['idserial'];
    $matasessao = "ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION :IDSESSAO, :IDSERIAL IMMEDIATE";
    $prepare = oci_parse($connect,$matasessao);
    oci_bind_by_name($prepare, ':IDSESSAO', $IDSESSAO);
    oci_bind_by_name($prepare, ':IDSERIAL', $IDSERIAL);
    $resultado = oci_execute($prepare);
    }   
    if (isset($_POST['kill'])) {
    mataSessao();
}
```

Ela tá retornando

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\script\index.php on line 61

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\script\index.php on line 62

Warning: oci_execute(): in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\script\index.php on line 63

Obrigado desde já, galera.

Comment: Não parece ser um erro ... tem mais algum texto na mensagem?

Comment: Não, apenas isso. Mas o meu comando não surte nenhum efeito no sistema. Chamo a função assim: if (isset($_POST['kill'])) {mataSessao();
} e o sistema retorna esses avisos. Por um momento pensei que ele estava pegando os valores nulos, mas dei um echo e vi que estava normal.

Comment: Lembre também de mandar um `commit` para dizer que a transação terminou

Comment: creio eu que nesse comando ALTER KILL pode ser que não aceite parâmetro de referência, Você já tentou enviar direto, para ver o que acontece? `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION $idsessao, $idserial IMMEDIATE`

Comment: – adventistaam, fazendo assim, só aparece o Warning: oci_execute(): in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\script\index.php on line 63

Answer (score 1):

Tente o seguinte:

```
function mataSessao(){
    $connect = oci_connect('xxxx','xxxx','xxxxx','xxxxx');
    $IDSESSAO = $_POST['idsessao'];
    $IDSERIAL = $_POST['idserial'];
    $matasessao = "ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION ':IDSESSAO, :IDSERIAL' IMMEDIATE";
    $prepare = oci_parse($connect,$matasessao);
    oci_bind_by_name($prepare, ':IDSESSAO', $IDSESSAO);
    oci_bind_by_name($prepare, ':IDSERIAL', $IDSERIAL);
    $resultado = oci_execute($prepare);
    }   
    if (isset($_POST['kill'])) {
    mataSessao();
}
```

O comando kill session recebe uma string com o SID e o serial separados por virgula nesta ordem. A seguir segu documentação da oracle com a sintaxe do comando: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/manproc008.htm#ADMIN11192